# Why specifying "anaconda" channel was required while installing numpy in py37 env

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, anaconda

Just installed Anaconda on MacOS with python2 and created a new environment with python3. New to Anaconda and realized that this new environment didn't have any modules installed. Tried to run `conda install anaconda` or `conda install numpy` to get numpy, matplotlib, etc. installed (I'm following [those instructions](https://salishsea-meopar-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/work_env/python3_conda_environment.html)) but kept getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

even though I'm running the right binary :

```
Alexandres-MBP ~ which python
/anaconda2/envs/py37/bin/python
```

Finally installed numpy, matplotlib and scipy respectively with

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
conda install matplotlib
conda install scipy
```

But I don't understand why I had to specify the 'anaconda' channel for numpy but not for the other. Anyone?

Edit : any way to automatically install those modules automatically when creating a new environment, as it's the case with the default environment set up with Anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda comes with `numpy`. Did you install `miniconda`?

Comment: Nope. Full Anaconda. My (default) py27 environment *has* numpy, matplotlib, etc. but the new one I created for py37 had nothing.

Comment: I think the usual way of creating the environment would be to use `conda create -n myenv python=3.7 matplotlib scipy` (since numpy is a dependency of both matplotlib and scipy, conda should get the according version of numpy automatically.